# Angular 8 - HttpInterceptor - read response headers

Tags: angular, http-headers, response, angular-http-interceptors

I am missing http headers in a response from my HttpInterceptor. I can get a body but not headers. Please see attached output and my code.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiVersionInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(
        req: import("@angular/common/http").HttpRequest<any>,
        next: import("@angular/common/http").HttpHandler
    ): import("rxjs").Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap(httpEvent=>{
                // Skip request
                if(httpEvent.type === 0){
                    return;
                }
                console.log("response: ", httpEvent);
            })

        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wohoo I fixed my problem.

It is not Angular problem but server problem. I need to add another header:

```
"access-control-expose-headers": "mintargetapiversion"
```

Angular ignores custom headers if they are not specified in "access-control-expose-header"

Answer (score 3):

Use **`httpEvent.headers.get()`** method like shown below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiVersionInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(
        req: import("@angular/common/http").HttpRequest<any>,
        next: import("@angular/common/http").HttpHandler
    ): import("rxjs").Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap((httpEvent: HttpEvent<any>) =>{
                // Skip request
                if(httpEvent.type === 0){
                    return;
                }           
                console.log("response: ", httpEvent);

                let minTargetApiVersion : string;
                if (httpEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    if(httpEvent.headers.has('mintargetapiversion')) {
                        minTargetApiVersion = httpEvent.headers.get('mintargetapiversion');
                    }
                }
            })

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but error: Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any>' appears. I was unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: I fixed it by tap((httpEvent: any)=>{ , but the IF statement is always false. httpEvent.headers.get('mintargetapiversion') will always return null.

Comment: I was wondering why the http headers weren't listed in that first console log and after adding in your `if (httpEvent instanceof HttpResponse) { ...`, it works like a charm. This works in combination with the header `"access-control-expose-headers"` to read non-standard http headers. Thank you!