# Read asp.net core http response header in angular app with http interceptor

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I try to do a simple appversion check by sending the current server version to the client in the http header and if there's a newer version, it should notify the user to reload. I thought this will be an easy task but my angular interceptor doesn't get my new response header sent by asp.net core. I use .Net6 and Angular 13.

#### Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   context.Response.Headers.Add("X-AppVersion", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.GetName().Version!.ToString());
   await next();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                {
                    var headers = context.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                    headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                    {
                        NoCache = true,
                        NoStore = true,
                        MustRevalidate = true,
                        MaxAge = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                    // Not sure about this one
                    headers.Append("X-AppVersion", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.GetName().Version!.ToString());
                }
            };
        });
```

#### Angular interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   const reqWithCredentials = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
   return next.handle(reqWithCredentials).pipe(
    map(resp => {
      if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
        if (resp.headers.get('x-appversion')) {
          console.log(resp.headers.get('x-appversion'));
        } else {
          console.log(null); // I always get null
        }
        return resp;
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60169458/11719787) answer your question?

Comment: @Sameer Nope, I had to move this middleware config *before* UseEndpoints().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move my app.Use() middleware configuration **before** app.UseEndpoints() for this to work.

related: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18768